# Como se declara un elemento a* , b?, (a | b) en XSD

Tags: xml

Quiero decir como seria esta declaración en DTD a XSD

```
 <!ELEMENT ejemplo (a*, b)> <!ELEMENT ejemplo (a, b?)> <!ELEMENT ejemplo (a | b)>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le cambié de nombre a los elemenos para poder usar los 3 a la vez.

```
<!ELEMENT ejemplo1 (a*, b)> <!ELEMENT ejemplo2 (a, b?)> <!ELEMENT ejemplo3 (a | b)>
```

En XSD sería de la siguiente manera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="ejemplo1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="a" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="b"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ejemplo2">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="a"/>
                <xs:element ref="b" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ejemplo3">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="a"/>
                <xs:element ref="b"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="b">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="a">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Una pregunta, estoy de acuerdo con el ejemplo 1 y 3 pero el "2" por que en el b solo pones minOccurs="0" y no pones maxOccurs="1", es decir esta o no está. Gracias por tu respuesta. Y bueno lo ultimo que has puesto después del ultimo elemento que significa. Decir que recién empiezo con XML. De nuevo gracias

Comment: @RonaldSanchez, si no pones `maxOccurs`, el valor de este atributo es `1` por definición.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Muchas gracias por tu aclaración!